# How do I convert this array into a string?

Tags: ruby

So I have an object that is an array with values like this:

```
["39/13/36", "39/13/38/39", "39/13/38/35"]
```

I would like to convert that into a string that looks like this:

```
39/13/36,39/13/38/39,39/13/38/35
```

How do I do that?

Comment: [`Array#join`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use join?   http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join

```
>> ["39/13/36", "39/13/38/39", "39/13/38/35"].join ','
=> "39/13/36,39/13/38/39,39/13/38/35"
>>
```